# Javascript dynamically add row below current row on mouseover and delete same row on mouse out

Tags: javascript

I am trying to add a row below the current row to a table on mouseover, display some information, and then remove the row on mouseout. Searching on Stack I found the function opentr() which adds the row below the current and it works with a button, but not a mouseover. I wrote the closetr() function and it also works, again for a button, but not a mouseout.

With a mouseover the function adds the row to the bottom, and then removes it on mouseout. A click adds the row below and also removes the row below which is the behavior I want, but with a mouseover/mouseout.

What do I need to do to get the mouseover/mouseout to add and remove the row below the hovered row? I'm looking for a pure JavaScript solution. Thanks for your help.

Here is my html:

```
<table id="table">
<tr>
  <td onmouseover="opentr(this);" onmouseout="closetr(this);">A</td>
  <td>B</td>
  <td>C</td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>D</td>
  <td>E</td>
  <td>F</td>
  <td><a onclick ="opentr(this);">AddTR</a></td>
  <td><a onclick ="closetr(this);">RemoveTR</a></td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>G</td>
  <td>H</td>
  <td>I</td>
  <td><a onclick ="opentr(this);">AddTR</a></td>
  <td><a onclick ="closetr(this);">RemoveTR</a></td>
</tr>
<table>
```

and here is the javascript functions:

```
function opentr(el) {
    var currTR = el.parentNode.parentNode;
    var newTR = document.createElement("tr");
    newTR.innerHTML = "<td>"+currTR.rowIndex+"</td><td>"+newTR.rowIndex+" </td><td>"+(Math.floor(Math.random() * (1000 - 100) + 100))+"</td>";
    currTR.parentNode.insertBefore(newTR, currTR.nextSibling);
}

function closetr(el) {
    var currTR = el.parentNode.parentNode;
    var nextTR = currTR.nextSibling;
    document.all("table").deleteRow(nextTR.rowIndex);
}
```

Comment: Why not add the row unconditionally, then show/hide it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could modify the JS.  The issue is that el.parentNode.parentNode gives the parent tr for your a tags, but the table for the mouseover and mouseout element.

```
function opentr(el) {
    var currTR = el.closest("tr");
    var newTR = document.createElement("tr");
    newTR.innerHTML = "<td>"+currTR.rowIndex+"</td><td>"+newTR.rowIndex+" </td><td>"+(Math.floor(Math.random() * (1000 - 100) + 100))+"</td>";
    currTR.parentNode.insertBefore(newTR, currTR.nextSibling);
}

function closetr(el) {
    var currTR = el.closest("tr");
    var nextTR = currTR.nextSibling;
    document.all("table").deleteRow(nextTR.rowIndex);
}
```

Comment: Ahhh!, Thank you!